# I have created a table in hive, I would like to know which directory my table is created in?

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have created a table in hive, I would like to know which directory my table is created in? I would like to know the path...

Answer (score 108):

`DESCRIBE FORMATTED my_table;`

or

`DESCRIBE FORMATTED my_table PARTITION (my_column='my_value');`

Comment: This answer is excellent... Thank you very much Joe... I can find every thing here about my table.

Comment: This works very fine.. Any idea how we can see all partitions info in one command?

Comment: I have a maprfs system. I am trying to find the location of the file for which hive view is created. I am describing the hive view. but i am not seeing the location option there. Can u help!

Answer (score 26):

There are three ways to describe a table in Hive.

1. To see table primary info of Hive table, use **describe table_name;** command
2. To see more detailed information about the table, use **describe extended table_name;** command
3. To see code in a clean manner use **describe formatted table_name;** command to see all information. also describe all details in a clean manner.

Answer (score 15):

You can use below commands for the same.

```
show create table <table>;
desc formatted <table>;
describe formatted <table>;
```

Answer (score 13):

```
DESCRIBE FORMATTED <tablename>
```

or

```
DESCRIBE EXTENDED <tablename>
```

I prefer formatted because it is more human readable format

Answer (score 8):

To see both of the structure and location (directory) of an any (internal or external)table, we can use table's create statment-

```
show create table table_name;
```

Answer (score 5):

in hive 0.1 you can use `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to find the path where hive store data.

in other versions, there is no good way to do this.

upadted:

thanks Joe K

use `DESCRIBE FORMATTED <table>` to show table information.

ps: database.tablename is not supported here.

Comment: What can I do to see that info for a table in the non default database. I can't provide the database in that command?

Comment: confirmative.DESCRIBE FORMATTED <table> does work while SHOW CREATE TABLE does not work

Answer (score 3):

Further to pensz answer you can get more info using:

```
DESCRIBE EXTENDED my_table;
```

or

```
DESCRIBE EXTENDED my_table PARTITION (my_column='my_value');
```

Answer (score 2):

All `HIVE` managed tables are stored in the below `HDFS` location.

```
hadoop fs -ls /user/hive/warehouse/databasename.db/tablename
```

Comment: That looks very specific upon the installation/configuration, no ?

Comment: this is exactly the question

Answer (score 1):

If you use [Hue](http://gethue.com), you can browse the table in the Metastore App and then click on 'View file location': that will open the HDFS File Browser in its directory.

Answer (score 0):

in the 'default' directory if you have not specifically mentioned your location.

you can use describe and describe extended to know about the table structure.