# List of tables in same location

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have set of databases in hive, some of the tables are Managed and some are External tables. Now, i want to know list of tables which are located in same path.

For example for different databases A, B and C, 
External tables for A are stored at /x/y/a
Some tables for B are stored at /x/y/b, /x/y/d
External tables for C are stored at /x/y/c

It is possible with some hive query or properties? Please help.

Thanks

Comment: If you want to use only hive query, I think that this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13178182/i-have-created-a-table-in-hive-i-would-like-to-know-which-directory-my-table-is) would help.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of tables stored in HADOOP filesystem by using command :
`hdfs dfs -ls /user/hive/warehouse/**<DB_name>**.db`/

This will give list of Managed tables.