# Where is the data location of table data when I create a managed table without specifying LOCATION?

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig, hiveql

I created a managed table without specifying the location where data will be stored.I thought it will be in the user/hive/warehouse/ dir but the data is not there.When I did select * data is seen in the table.

So where is the data location in this scenario.Is it in the temp dir.

Comment: This will be useful to you: [hive warehouse location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058400/where-does-hive-store-its-files-in-hdfs)

Answer (score 1):

Go to hive shell and fire:

```
 SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name
```

You will see `location` in the output.

It should be your

```
hive_warehouse_directory/database_name.db/table_name
```