# how do you create a hive warehouse directory?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I've installed hadoop and hive. I am trying to configure hive as follows:

```
hadoop fs -mkdir       /data/hive/warehouse
```

I keep getting this error:

```
mkdir: '/data/hive/warehouse': No such file or directory
```

Do I need to create the directories with os commands before issuing the hadoop fs command? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `-p` option similar to UNIX/Linux.

```
$ hadoop fs -mkdir -p /data/hive/warehouse
```

In addition, you should also chmod 1777 this directory if you're setting this up for multiple users and add /user/hive if you're running Hive as user `hive`.

```
$ hadoop fs -chmod -R 1777 /data/hive/warehouse
$ hadoop fs -mkdir -p /user/hive
$ hadoop fs -chown hive:hive /user/hive
```

See [Apache Hive File System Permissions in CDH](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-14-x/topics/cdh_ig_filesystem_perm.html) and [Where does Hive store files in HDFS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058400/where-does-hive-store-files-in-hdfs).

Comment: -p option did not return any error but, when I go to /data/hive directory, I don't see any warehouse directory created.

Comment: What is the output of `hadoop fs -lsr /data`?